# Views exposed filter with selected tags/terms

Tags: views

I am importing RSS content with Feeds Module that is tagged with the Atom standard category-tag. I would like to give the user the opportunity to filter the content in a view, but only by some selected tags (as the tags imported are too many and I am not able to assign them to different vocabularies). I tried to achieve it with grouping, but only received empty results. Is it possible to offer filters that only offer some selected tags?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself: Sometimes it is so easy and obvious and you too are blind to see it:

- Choose selection type dropdown
- select terms
- check "Limit list to selected"